# Graphviz undefined reference to `_imp__agread' using Makefile

Tags: makefile, linker, graphviz, undefined-reference, lib

I'm a student trying to use Graphviz as an external library in my C project, using Windows. However, when I try to compile it, I receive undefined reference errors to the functions included in "gvc.h" and "cgraph.h". For example, agread and gvContext.

I've looked through many posts on the same topic but nothing suggested seemed to work for me as well.

Currently, I am only working on the Windows portion of my Makefile. Here it is in full:

```
.PHONY: all clean
#CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`
#LDLIBS = `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
CFLAGS = -I"C:/Program Files/Graphviz/include/graphviz"
LDIR = -L"C:/Program Files/Graphviz/lib"
LIBS = -lgvc -lcgraph

binaries=sqlpsql
all: $(binaries)

sqlpsql: SQLP.c SQLPGrammar.y SQLPScanner.l SQLPtoSQL-main.c Preprocess.c Rules.c
   
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
   win_bison -v -d SQLPGrammar.y
   win_flex --nounput -D SQLPGrammar SQLPScanner.l
   gcc -Wall -o sqlpsql SQLP.c SQLPtoSQL-main.c Preprocess.c Rules.c $(CFLAGS) $(LDIR) $(LIBS)
else
   bison -v -d SQLPGrammar.y
   flex --nounput -D SQLPGrammar SQLPScanner.l
   gcc -Wall SQLP.c SQLPtoSQL-main.c Preprocess.c Rules.c -o sqlpsql
   rm -f lex.yy.c SQLPGrammar.tab.c SQLPGrammar.tab.h
endif

clean:
   -rm -f *.o *.output $(binaries)
```

On my computer, the header files are in: C:/Program Files/Graphviz/include/graphviz

The lib files are in: C:/Program Files/Graphviz/lib

I have added both locations to the Makefile using the -I and -L tags, as above.

Along with a very simple main function invoking the two functions (in another file), here is my SQLP.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gvc.h>
#include <cgraph.h>
#include "SQLP.h"

void generate_graph(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("C:/Users/claud/Documents/UW/4A/Roseseed/test.dot", "w+");
    fputs("digraph ERD {\n", fp);
    fputs("graph [   rankdir = \"LR\" ];\n", fp);
    fputs("ranksep=2;\n", fp);
    fputs("\"SCOTT.DEPT\" [ label=\"<SCOTT.DEPT> SCOTT.DEPT|<PK_DEPT>DEPTNO \\l |DNAME \\l LOC \\l \" shape = \"record\" ];\n", fp);
    fputs("\"SCOTT.EMP\" [ label=\"<SCOTT.EMP> SCOTT.EMP|<FK_DEPTNO>DEPTNO \\l |EMPNO \\l ENAME \\l JOB \\l MGR \\l STARTDATE \\l SAL \\l COMM \\l \" shape = \"record\" ];\n", fp);
    fputs("\"SCOTT.DEPT\":\"PK_DEPT\"->\"SCOTT.EMP\":\"FK_DEPTNO\" [arrowhead = crow];}\n", fp);
    fclose(fp);

    export_graph();    
}

void export_graph(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("C:/Users/claud/Documents/UW/4A/Roseseed/test.dot", "r");
    Agraph_t *g;
    g = agread(fp, 0);
    GVC_t *gvc;
    gvc = gvContext();
    gvLayout(gvc, g, "dot");
    gvRender(gvc, g, "png", 
        fopen("C:/Users/claud/Documents/UW/4A/Roseseed/test.png", "w"));
    gvFreeLayout(gvc, g);
    agclose(g);
}
```

All other files compile properly because they do not include these header files.

And here is the full output of running make on Git Bash in the location of the Makefile:

```
$ make
win_bison -v -d SQLPGrammar.y
win_flex --nounput -D SQLPGrammar SQLPScanner.l
gcc -Wall -o sqlpsql SQLP.c SQLPtoSQL-main.c Preprocess.c Rules.c -I"C:/Program Files/Graphviz/include/graphviz" -L"C:/Program Files/Graphviz/lib" -lgvc -lcgraph
C:\Users\claud\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEwgb5N.o:SQLP.c:(.text+0x3abe): undefined reference to `_imp__agread'
C:\Users\claud\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEwgb5N.o:SQLP.c:(.text+0x3ac8): undefined reference to `_imp__gvContext'
C:\Users\claud\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEwgb5N.o:SQLP.c:(.text+0x3ae7): undefined reference to `_imp__gvLayout'
C:\Users\claud\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEwgb5N.o:SQLP.c:(.text+0x3b1b): undefined reference to `_imp__gvRender'
C:\Users\claud\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEwgb5N.o:SQLP.c:(.text+0x3b2f): undefined reference to `_imp__gvFreeLayout'
C:\Users\claud\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEwgb5N.o:SQLP.c:(.text+0x3b3c): undefined reference to `_imp__agclose'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:13: sqlpsql] Error 1
```

It seems like the header files are found, just none of the functions are defined. What can I do to fix this and compile the project? I am a beginner, any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Please edit your question and (with proper formatting, as you did with the makefile) cut and paste (not paraphrase) the exact compiler command line make prints out and (a sampling of, if there are too many) the exact error messages you get.  I don't know much about Windows or Graphviz but this doesn't look wrong so far as it goes.  Maybe there are other libraries, besides `gvc`, you need to link?

Comment: @MadScientist thanks for your advice! I edited my post to include the exact error message I get.

Comment: I tried to include the library cgraph, which gvc.h includes but this did not help either (edited the Makefile to show this). I assume it wouldn't be necessary to include every single library in the Makefile but I tried it anyways and still did not work...

Comment: Update - I did find this link: https://graphviz.org/dot.demo/Makefile
It features the following two lines:
CFLAGS=pkg-config libgvc --cflags -Wall -g -O2
LDFLAGS=pkg-config libgvc --libs
which may be needed? But when I include them, I get /usr/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found

Comment: Those lines only work on POSIX systems like GNU/Linux.  They won't work on Windows.  On Linux they will print out the correct flags needed to compile and link so they can be included in the command line.  On Windows, I guess you have to figure it out for yourself.  Maybe look in the documentation.  Sorry I can't help more: you'll need someone who knows about Graphviz on Windows.  If no one chimes in here maybe there are some help forums for Graphviz.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I posted a question on the Graphviz forum here and was able to receive an answer. There was nothing wrong, and it seemed to work with a different compiler (MingW64), so I'll take it: https://forum.graphviz.org/t/undefined-reference-to-imp-agread/850/